# c If or elseif boolean

Tags: c, if-statement, boolean

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char odd, even, answer;
    int x = -16;
    printf("Choose, even or odd?");
    scanf("%c", &answer);
    if (answer == odd)
    {
        while (x < 15)
        {
            x++;
            if (!(x % 2 == 1) && !(x % 2 == -1))
                continue;
            printf("%d\n", x);
        }
        printf("Look! Odd numbers!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else if (answer == even)
    {
        while (x < 15)
        {
            x++;
            if ((x % 2 == 1) && (x % 2 == -1))
                continue;
            printf("%d\n", x);
        }
        printf("Look! Even numbers!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("That's not a valid response");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Sorry I'm new to this and have run into a problem.

The output always ends up being the "else" option.

What am I doing wrong with the Boolean for if and else if?

Comment: `odd` is not initialized. Depending on your compiler, it's either `\0` which the user's almost never going to enter, or some garbage which would be a toss up as to whether it'll ever match what the user enters.

Comment: Yep, odd and even have garbage values.

Comment: Avoid using `scanf` to input `char` values, use `getchar()` instead. If you use `scanf` it may require an extra statement like `fflush(stdin)` or a dummy `getchar()` to flush the input stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize your variables. Right now they don't contain anything useful. If you want the user to type 'e' for 'even' and 'o' for 'odd', replace the first line in your function with something like:

```
char odd = 'o', even = 'e', answer = '\0';
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved it perfectly and now I know to initialize.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem is that you missed quotation marks ('...').  Also, type char is a character such as 'A' and can't be a word like 'odd'.  And therefore, the user should have to enter a character like 'o' for odd and 'e' for even, rather than the strings "odd and "even"

As Jason also stated, you have to initialize odd and even to fix the problem

Comment: `even` and `odd` are definitely of type `char`, they're just not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Remember quotation marks!

```
if (answer == "odd")
{
DOwhatever
}
```

Comment: C will compare the pointers if you do that. It will *not* compare the string contents (you need to use strcmp for that!)

Comment: I thought you were Tyranitar.

Comment: What do you mean Hot Licks? The Pokemon?

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare strings to strings, not characters to characters (this is assuming that you want your user to type in the words "even" or "odd"). Also, in your original code, `odd` and `even` are undefined variables. Make sure you include the string library:

```
#include <string.h>
```

Then, do something like the following:

```
char answer[5];
int x = -16;
printf("Choose, even or odd?");
fgets(&answer, 5, stdin);

if (strncpy(answer, "odd", sizeof answer) == 0)
{
    // ...
}
else if (strncpy(answer, "even", sizeof answer) == 0)
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    // ...
}
```

If, instead, you wanted the user to simply type in a single character (`e` or `o`), take a look at [Jason Coco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18501594/558592).

Comment: this is a stack overrun waiting to happen... not only are you overwriting the address of a dangling pointer, but it points into nonsense by the time `strcmp(3)` is called and you're not even using a pseudo-safe version of `strcmp(3)`

Comment: You need to declare a size for the char array. Arrays without a size, like `char foo[]`, are only allowed as function arguments.

Comment: Whoops, I haven't worked with C for a while. Let me fix that.

Comment: There's also no safe way to do this with `scanf(3)`, you should just create a stack array of some useful size like 10 and use `fgets(3)` to read the string and use `strncmp(3)` to compare it